# getting error "Your purchase couldn't be completed".in paypal .

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

[image: i getting this page after click to send button in live server. but when the sam e code is applied in localhost it works fine.]

this image which test in localhost [image]

view.blade.php`

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"  target="PPDGFrame" class="standard" id='paypal_id' accept-charset="utf-8">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{!! $send_money->financial_account->paypal_account !!}">
                        <!--  -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Tansfer"/>
                        <!--   <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="test_ipn" value="1" />-->
                        <input  type="hidden" name="expType" value="instant">
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="{!! $send_money->withdraw_amount !!}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="buyer_credit_promo_code" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="buyer_credit_product_category" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="kushwahavikas1993@gmail.com">
                        <!-- {!! Config::get('constants.Paypal_account')  !!} -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="buyer_credit_user_address_change" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
                        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
                        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://example.com/cancel.php'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/softral/public/admin/financial/requestMoney/getDone'>
                        <input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="Softral Payment"/>
                        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">

                        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
                        <input type="submit" value="Pay!"/>

                        </form>`
```

I dont undersatnd what went wrong with this code any solution  will be highly appriciated.

Comment: As error suggests, there must be some issue with business paypal email, please confirm whether you are getting correct value in place of {!! $send_money->financial_account->paypal_account !!}

Comment: i check using static paypal account but getting same error

Comment: There is no error in piece of HTML/PHP code, I have replaced with my sandbox email business account. Probably you are passing your email address using which you created paypal account. It is needed to create business account after login to paypal sandbox.

Comment: i create a paypal business account kushwahavikas1993-1@gmail.com in sandbox but getting same error

Comment: Clear your browser cache or try another browser as I have replace the HTML with kushwahavikas1993-1@gmail.com and completed the process with tx - 76S41078V0423124G.